# PHP SimpleXML asXML writes ANSI encoded file

Tags: php, utf-8, simplexml

I am trying to write some content into an XML file, yet I do have problems with special characters.

The content I'd like to write is submitted to the script via `$_GET`, so I assume it is properly decoded into UTF-8 content.

```
$write = $_GET['content'];
```

will be fed like:

```
file.php?content=s%F6per
```

In the PHP I do the following:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$newentry = $xml -> addChild('element',$write);
$xml -> asXML($xml_filename);
```

The XML file that is opened is UTF-8 encoded. When I write content without any of those "problem characters" the asXML will save the file in UTF-8 again. As soon as I insert special characters it gets saved in ANSI encoding, messing up the file as I won't be able to open it (the script will complain about improper encoding) anymore.

What am I missing? Reading the manual gives me the impression that I should be doing everything ok (i.e. not messing with the `$_GET['content']`), so I unfortunately have no clue.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your special characters does not look a UTF-8, but a ISO-8859-1 character

see here - http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Possible solution

```
$newentry = $xml->addChild('element', htmlentities($write));
```

Or

```
$newentry = $xml->addChild('element', iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $write));
```

And off-topic, please avoid using `$_GET` to write something into file or insert into database, is risky

Comment: Thanks! No. 2 did the trick, although I still don't really get why the URL-encoded special characters will be translated into ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 (when my PHP-file is UTF-8). Anyways thank you!

Comment: simply because the input is NOT in UTF-8, maybe you need to examine how you construct the `$_GET`

Comment: But how would I UTF-8 encode a query string? Thanks for the safety tip by the way, I am aware of that and "have taken measures".

Comment: Ok, got it, I don't encode it at all... Should have thought of that myself, the problem was that I wasn't aware that the percent-encoded special characters will result in ISO-encoding. Thanks alot!