# Parsing funny characters like á with SimpleXML

Tags: php, character-encoding, xml-parsing, simplexml

When receiving and writing my XML, some of the fields are coming through like this: `Benedíková`

But when I parse it out with code like

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename); 
print_r($xml);
```

...the field changes to this:

`BenedÃ­kovÃ¡`

How can I parse it cleanly so that characters like á or í are retained?

Answer (score 0):

As it is documented in the PHP manual, when you read strings out of a `SimpleXMLElement` is is always in Unicode using the UTF-8 encoding.

This is independent to the encoding used inside the document.

So if your website does not use UTF-8 as the encoding you might want to switch to it *or* you might want to re-encode those UTF-8 strings into the encoding of your website.

I would normally suggest the first (convert the website to use UTF-8) but it's not always easily possible to change it (and not always the right thing to do), so both variants have their use.

See as well:

- [simplexml_load_string() doesn't like foreign languages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5943555/367456) (Exact Duplicate from May 2011)
- [PHP SimpleXML asXML writes ANSI encoded file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6940104/367456)